# Stripe, how to include multiple products in a Checkout session?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I'm new to the Stripe API and I am trying to implement the [prebuilt Checkout page](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/integration-builder) for my ecommerce site. I want a customer to be able to purchase at most 6 items, and I want those 6 items to be featured on the checkout page.

The [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create) mentions that line_items is a "list of items the customer is purchasing," so I have 6 objects in the line_items array for each product; however, stripe.sessions.create() doesn't execute and the Checkout page doesn't load. If I remove all but 1  of the objects in line_items, the session works and the page is loaded.

Below is from my backend that handles the request for creating a Checkout session. Any help is appreciated!

```js
app.post('/create-session', async (req, res) => {

    const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:3000/Home';

    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      line_items: [
        {
          price_data: {
            currency: 'usd',
            product_data: {
              name: 'Product1',
              images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
            },
            unit_amount: 1899,
          },
          quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                name: 'Product2',
                images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
                },
                unit_amount: 1899,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                name: 'Product3',
                images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
                },
                unit_amount: 1899,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                name: 'Product4',
                images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
                },
                unit_amount: 1899,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                name: 'Product5',
                images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
                },
                unit_amount: 1899,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        },
        {
            price_data: {
                currency: 'usd',
                product_data: {
                name: 'Product6',
                images: ['https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png'],
                },
                unit_amount: 1899,
            },
            quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      mode: 'payment',
      success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true`,
      cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
    });
    res.json({ id: session.id });
  });
```

**EDIT:**
I am using stripe-node 8.119.0.

In the Stripe developer logs, I am getting a 400 error for POST /v1/checkout/sessions. This is the response body:

```js
    {
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_invalid_integer",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",
    "message": "This value must be greater than or equal to 1.",
    "param": "line_items[1][quantity]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

On the frontend, I am getting the following in my console:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2HMa.png)

Comment: "stripe.sessions.create() doesn't execute and the Checkout page doesn't load" Is there an error message in your console, or in the Stripe developer logs?

Comment: As @ceejayoz says: can you provide more detail? This looks correct/valid, so we'll need any errors to help you debug. Can you share which version of `stripe-node` you're using and what your default API version is?

Comment: My stripe-node version is 8.119.0.

I'm not getting any issues in my backend, but my Stripe developer console shows there is a 400 error for POST /v1/checkout/sessions:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_invalid_integer",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-invalid-integer",
    "message": "This value must be greater than or equal to 1.",
    "param": "line_items[1][quantity]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}

Comment: Are your quantities coming out of a variable or database somewhere? Or are they always hard-coded to `quantity: 1` as shown in the example above? The Stripe developer console should show what you *sent* as well as what they responded; does it match up?

Comment: @creejayoz Yeah, my quantities are temporarily hardcoded. But in a previous version I had them dependent on a state starting from value 0, and it looks like I hadn't fully updated my backend. It's working now that every quantity is hardcoded to 1, so it seems that quantities set to 0 caused the issue. If you don't mind me asking another question, does this mean I can't always have all 6 products defined in the checkout session? My approach was going to be to have all 6 defined in every session, but have quantity vary (starting from 0) depending on how much product is selected in the frontend.

Comment: Correct, just leave them off if the quantity is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what is working for me in PHP:

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
      'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
      'line_items' => [ 
      [
        'price_data' => [
          'currency' => 'usd',
          'unit_amount' => 2000,
          'product_data' => [
            'name' => 'test',
          ],
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
      [
        'price_data' => [
          'currency' => 'usd',
          'unit_amount' => 1000,
          'product_data' => [
            'name' => 'test1',
          ],
        ],
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
      ],
      'mode' => 'payment',
      'success_url' => $return_url,
      'cancel_url' => $return_url,
    ]);
```

Looks like your unit_amount may be not nested correctly?

Comment: same in node js:

```const items = [
  {
    'price_data': {
      currency: 'usd',
      unit_amount: 2000,
      product_data: {
        name: 'test',
      },
    },
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',
      unit_amount: 1000,
      product_data: {
        name: 'test1',

      },
    },
    quantity: 1,
  },
];
```